# Possible to reload top-level React Native component in order to refresh all children components?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on an iPad app that needs to reset itself at midnight each night. Most of the children components contain data that needs to be wiped or refreshed for the new day. Is it possible to reload (forceUpdate() didn't do the trick) the whole app programmatically?

I realize it's counter to the React paradigm, but seems overly complicated to change some dummy state in all the children to reset them!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forceUpdate() is a lifecycle function but using it to update a child component is not prefered until and unless it is there is no way, instead use setState to update child component.